# Delphi Recursive function replace string

Tags: delphi, function, recursion, replace

I tried replace found text recursively but i cant get it working.
This will replace only 1 ´a´ char before each ´text´ but i want replace all ´a´ characters before text

```
//Declared recursive function
function OneLine(s:WideString):WideString;
begin
s:=StringReplace(s,'atext', 'text', [rfReplaceAll]);

if (Pos(Result,'atext')>0) then
 begin
 //XMLstring:=Result;
 s:=OneLine(XMLstring);
 end
 else
 begin
 Result:=XMLstring;
 end;
end;

//--Here begins program
Var
t:string
Begin

//exaple of text 
//we need replace all 'a' before 'text' only
t:='aaHaaatextaaaatextHHaatextHHaaaa';

//call custom recursive function
t:=OneLine(t); 

ShowMessage(t);

End.
```

I need replace this: 'aaHaaatextaaaatextHHaatextHHaaaa'

final text should looks like this: 'aaHtexttextHHtextHHaaaa'

Comment: Read the documentation for `Pos`, the first argument is the string you're searching for. Then put a breakpoint on the same line and examine what does `Result` hold when the breakpoint is hit.

Comment: You should use a for with an if inside and you will solve your problem easily ;)

Comment: What is XMLString? Copy and paste your real code.

Comment: When you say you "can't get it working," what does that mean? What did you do to try to get it working, and how did your efforts fail? Stack Overflow is not the place to ask people to debug your code for you. Debugging is *your* job. What problem are you having in debugging this code yourself? Identify *that* problem, and then ask here how to overcome it.

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
function OneLine(const S, OldPattern, NewPattern: string):string;
begin
 Result:=s;
 repeat
  Result:=StringReplace(Result, OldPattern, NewPattern, [rfReplaceAll]);
 until Pos(OldPattern, Result)=0;
end;
```

and use like so

```
OneLine('aaHaaatextaaaatextHHaatextHHaaaa','atext','text')
```

Comment: Thanks but this is not recursive function. I already tried while loop and it worked, but i try to get working function which will call itself = recursive fuction

Comment: Why you need a recursive function?

Comment: Because it is not an efficient solution for your problem.

Comment: @Nafalem - so turn a loop into recursive function, what the problem ?

Answer (score 2):

Your recursive logic is wrong, not to mention more complex then it needs to be.  Try this instead:

```
function OneLine(const s: WideString): WideString;
begin
  if Pos(WideString('atext'), s) > 0 then
    Result := OneLine(StringReplace(s, 'atext', 'text', [rfReplaceAll]))
  else
    Result := s;
end;
```

Also, you do realize that `StringReplace()` does not support `WideString`, don't you? So you are doing a lot of unnecessary WideString-to-String-to-WideString data conversions at each step.  Change `OneLine()` to take and return a `String` instead so it can continue using `StringReplace()` and the `WideString` conversions are only performed at the initial call site:

```
function OneLine(const s: String): String;
begin
  if Pos('atext', s) > 0 then
    Result := OneLine(StringReplace(s, 'atext', 'text', [rfReplaceAll]))
  else
    Result := s;
end;
```

Or else re-implement `OneLine()` to stop using `StringReplace()` altogether and instead manually search-and-replace using `WideString` values exclusively.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks this helped me alot. I used widestring function because of unicode support, but it seems also string functions work with UTF-8 (probably it depends on version of Delphi, i used Turbo delhpi 7). 
I used it to format a strings in UTF-8-encoded xml file.

```
function OneLineCDATA(const s: String): String;
begin
  if Pos(#9+'<![CDATA[', s) > 0 then
    Result := OneLineCDATA(StringReplace(s, #9+'<![CDATA[', '<![CDATA[', [rfReplaceAll]))
  else
    if Pos(#13+#10+'<![CDATA[', s) > 0 then
      Result := OneLineCDATA(StringReplace(s, #13+#10+'<![CDATA[', '<![CDATA[', [rfReplaceAll]))
     else
        if Pos(']]>'+#13+#10, s) > 0 then
          Result := OneLineCDATA(StringReplace(s, ']]>'+#13+#10, ']]>', [rfReplaceAll]))
        else
          if Pos(']]>'+#9, s) > 0 then
            Result := OneLineCDATA(StringReplace(s, ']]>'+#9, ']]>', [rfReplaceAll]))
           else
             Result := s;

end;
```

Comment: Pain awaits. Use real XML library.